# derivation of energy function on image processing

Tags: image-processing

If we build an energy function in a image, which contains a neighborhood smoothness term, how do we get the derivative of this energy function?

Suppose the energy term is

```
\begin{equation*}
    \sum_{\{x,y\} \in N} (\beta(x)-\beta(y))K(x,y)
\end{equation*}
```

where `N` is the first-order neighbor. `K(x,y)` is the weight calculated by `I(x)` and `I(y)`.

How do we get the derivative and How to get its matrix form? 
Please provide some references, thank you.